# How to prevent letters from being entered in the input module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I need to make it so that only numbers can be entered in the input (a and b), and throw an error letters when  letters are passed.

Here is my code:

````
from colorama import init 
init() 
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
povt = True

print(Fore.GREEN + "\nMAX-calc")

while povt == True:
    

    what = input(Fore.WHITE + "\nAction " + Fore.GREEN + "(+,-, ×, /): " + Fore.YELLOW)
    
    a = input (Fore.WHITE + "First number: " + Fore.YELLOW)
    b = input(Fore.WHITE + "Second number: " + Fore.YELLOW) 
    
    psh = input("Enter y: ")
    if psh == "y":
        if not a:
            a=0
        if not b:
            b=0
   
    if what == "+":
            c=float(a)+float(b)
            print(Back.YELLOW + Fore.BLACK + "Addition result:" + str(c))
    elif what == "-":
        c=float(a)-float(b)
        print(Back.YELLOW + Fore.BLACK +"Subtraction result:" + str(c))
    elif what == "×":
        c=float(a)*float(b)
        print(Back.YELLOW + Fore.BLACK +"Multiplication result:" + str(c))       
    elif what == "/":
        c=float(a)/float(b)
        print(Back.YELLOW + Fore.BLACK +"Division result:" + str(c)) 
    else:
        print(Back.RED + Fore.BLACK + "Sorry, I don't know what a " + what + ", is, but I'll try to figure it out > ͜ 0 ")
        
    povto = input("Retry? (y, n): " + Back.BLACK + Fore.YELLOW)
    
    if povto == "n":
        povt = False
    elif povto == "y":
        povt = True   
    else:
        povt = False
        print(Back.RED + Fore.BLACK + "OK... we will assume that the " + povto + " - means no > ͜ 0```
````

Comment: @EmiOB tried but couldn't find anything like it.  Thanks.

Comment: it is basically the same answer as both the answers given below

Answer (score 0):

A potential way of solving this would be:

```
keep_asking = True
while keep_asking:
    a = input("Please input a number: ")
    try:
        a = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        keep_asking = False
```

Essentially, this means that the binary variable `keep_asking` will remain `True` (and hence the loop will keep asking) as long as the type casting via `int()` fails, but as soon as it succeeds that variable will flip to `False`, and the loop will not be executed further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this inside your input-loop:

```py
while True:
    try:
        a = float(input(Fore.WHITE + "First number: " + Fore.YELLOW))
    except:
        print(Fore.RED + "Please enter a number!")
    else:
        break
```

This tries to cast the input to float (or any other type you want) and will only move on if you input a number.